# Div loses its height,width on second double click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to popout a div (whose visibility is originally set to hidden) on capturing the double click event on a canvas. It works perfect/as expected on the first 'double' click. When I double click the same canvas a second time to popout, the height and width of the div is lost.

I did try setting the div's display to none and block instead of visibility, I noticed that the div's display changes to inline-block on the second double click. Am I missing something?

Here's the code of what I am trying to do.

```js
calloutCVS.addEventListener('dblclick', function(evt) {
  isZoomed = 1;
  $('#zoomPopup')[0].style.visibility = "visible";
  drawZoomedCanvas();

  $('#zoomPopup').popup({
    type: 'overlay',
    horizontal: 'center',
    vertical: 'center',
    opacity: 0.3,
    escape: true,
    blur: true
  });


  $('#zoomPopup').popup({
    onclose: function() {
      isZoomed = 0;
      $('#zoomPopup')[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  });

  $('#zoomPopup').popup('show');

}, false);

var drawZoomedCanvas = function() {
  var currentDIVID = "zoomPopup";
  if (currentDIVID != undefined) {
    $('#' + currentDIVID).empty();
  }

  $("#" + currentDIVID).empty();
  var canvasid = "idZoomCVS";
  $("#" + currentDIVID).append("<canvas id=" + canvasid + " style='position:absolute;border:1px solid blue;'></canvas>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="zoomPopup" style="height:80%;width:80%;background:white;visibility:hidden;">
</div>
```

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: calloutCVS is not defined"

Comment: calloutCVS is the base canvas id on which I m capturing the double click event